# Error: expect a ';' before curly bracket

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Hey guys my brain has officially gone mush with all these projects since i can seem to figure out this relatively simple bug.

So the issue that i am having is that it is asking me to add a semi-colon before the curli bracket, here is the piece of code where it is happening.

```
bool IsAlive(int row, int col){
        return true;
    }
```

It is asking me a semi-colon right after 'col)'
Here is the full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define NumGen 1
#define NumRows 13
#define NumCol 13

using namespace std;


void main()
{
    const int NumModRows=NumRows+2;
    const int NumModCol=NumCol+2;
    int grid[NumGen][NumModRows][NumModCol]={0};
    grid[NumGen][0][0]=5;
    //cout<<"Hey this is number "<<grid[NumGen][0][0]<<endl;
    //int upLeft=-1, upMid=-1, upRight=-1, left=-1, right=-1, botLeft=-1, botMid=-1, botRight=-1;
    //cout<<"All: "<<upLeft<<", "<<upMid<<", "<<upRight<<", "<<left<<", "<<right<<", "<<botLeft<<", "<<botMid<<", "<<botRight<<endl<<endl;
    //get input from user

    int rowInput;
    int colInput;
    int numInputs;
    cout<<"how many inputs will be inserted in the grid?(in row then col format)"<<endl;
    //get user inputs where the gen 0 cells are alive
    for(int i=0; i<numInputs;i++)
    {
        cout<<"The row of input"<<endl;
        cin>>rowInput;
        cout<<"The col of input"<<endl;
        cin>>colInput;
        grid[NumGen][rowInput][colInput]=1;
    }

    //bool isAlive(int, int);
    bool IsAlive(int row, int col){
        return true;
    }



    //cin.get();

    Sleep(10000);

}
```

Comment: you IsAlive function is residing inside your main function. Declare it outside your main and you're good.

Comment: There are other things which lead to some quirks, e.g. `grid[NumGen][...][...]`.

Comment: A good (and pretty mechanical) technique to understand why something won't work is to remove chunks of code until you are left with the minimal example showing the problem. Then look at the resulting, minimal code very hard. Also http://sscce.org.

Comment: You could declare `IsAlive` as a lambda, but it's bad practice to just declare lambdas everywhere rather than free-functions

Answer (score 8):

You **can't** define another function `isAlive` inside `main`.

You may try to move the definition of the `isAlive` function outside `main`, then call the function inside `main` whenever necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Is alive is declared **inside** the main function

```
void main()
{
    //bool isAlive(int, int);
    bool IsAlive(int row, int col){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Move it outside

```
//bool isAlive(int, int);
bool IsAlive(int row, int col){
    return true;
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Please `int main() {}` for C+&#! sake

Comment: Sorry, I - literally - lol'd. Copied and pasted original source, didn't even see it :)